# Error while creating self-signed SSL certificate

Tags: security, ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I tried to create a self-signed certificate based on the instructions in the link in [Security key and cert for mosca MQTT broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913842/security-key-and-cert-for-mosca-mqtt-broker).

```
$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out tls-key.pem 1024 (works fine)

$ openssl req -new -key tlk-key -out server.csr (returns error)
```

The error looks like this on cygwin;

> Error opening Private Key tlk-key 6870300:error:02001002:system
>   library:fopen:No such file or
>   directory:bss_file.c:391:fopen('tlk-key','rb')
>   6870300:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system
>   lib:bss_file.c:393: unable to load Private Key

On Ubuntu 16.04, the error looks like this;

> Error opening Private Key tlk-key
>   140137729443480:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or
>   directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('tlk-key','r')
>   140137729443480:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system
>   lib:bss_file.c:400: unable to load Private Key

I tried with cygwin and Ubuntu. Can anyone advise what went wrong?

EDIT:
I tried the command below after getting the answer from Steffen Ullrich. It still returns an error.

```
$ openssl req -new -key tlk-key.pem -out server.csr
```

> Error opening Private Key tlk-key.pem 6870300:error:02001002:system
>   library:fopen:No such file or
>   directory:bss_file.c:391:fopen('tlk-key.pem','rb')
>   6870300:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system
>   lib:bss_file.c:393: unable to load Private Key

Comment: The documentation seems to be pretty old. 3DES should not be used anymore and for RSA the recommended key size is 2048.

Comment: Robert , thanks. Do you have any links that point to newer documentation?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the key file `tls-key.pem` but then try to use the non-existing file `tlk-key` instead of the file you've created:

```
$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out tls-key.pem 1024 (works fine)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
$ openssl req -new -key tlk-key -out server.csr (returns error)
                        ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I tried your answer but still get similar error. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @user91579631 now you are trying to read tlk-key.pem. You should be reading tls-key.pem.